# What default libraries does -nolibc remove?

Tags: gcc

I am working on a project which eventually requires me to link my code against my customized version of `libc`, `libstdc++` and `libgcc`. Now I am learning what libraries are linked by default.

I tried to compile my project code with `-nolibc` and manually provide the needed libraries in the argument list.

```
g++ -fuse-ld=gold -O2 -o main -static -nolibc main.cpp -lgcc -lm -lc
```

I got the following error, showing that I missed some libraries.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o):function _Unwind_Find_FDE: error: undefined reference to 'dl_iterate_phdr'
```

Which library is missing here?